# Using flag in matlap for secant method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matlab

In a book called optimization we have the following Algorithm for Secant method. Note that we are looking for zeroes of the derivative.

- Step 1: Given a, b, ε, and Δx, flag = 0;
- Step 2: Compute $α = (a+b)/2$, $f′(a)$ and $f′(α)$

  **If** $f′(a) f′(α) < 0$ **then** $b=α$, `set flag = 1 (zero is bracketed)` **else** $a=α$

  **If** `flag == 1` **then goto** Step 3 **else goto** Step 2
- Step 3: Compute $α = x_2 −f ′(x_2 )/ ((f ′(x_2 )− f ′(x_1))/(x_2 − x_1))$

  **If** $f′(α) > 0$ **then** $b=α$ **else** $a=α$

  **If** $|f′(α)|< ε$ **then goto** Step 4 **else goto** Step 3
- Step 4: Converged. **Print** $x^* = α$, $f(x^*) = f(α)$

---

My questions is

- What does the flag do and why it was 1 in step 2 and then 0 in step 3?
- What they mean by (zero is bracketed)?
- In step 3 why we say if $f′(α) > 0$

Can any one help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have changed $α=a+b/2$ which makes no sense to the midpoint formula. But given the parameter $Δx$, perhaps $α=a+Δx$ was originally intended?

Answer (score 1):

The code as presented will not work, it is missing some steps. (E.g., what are $x_1,x_2$?)

From the general structure, there are two stages, the **first stage** with the iterating *Step 2* is a line search for a *bracketing interval*.

> A **bracketing interval** is a guarantee of a root by the intermediate value theorem in that the function values at the interval end have opposite signs.

One would have to start with a large interval, and even then there is no guarantee that such an interval can be found.

In the **second stage**, iterating *Step 3*, the secant root is used as the midpoint of the interval. By ensuring the bracketing condition, this is the *regula falsi* or *false position method* with its slow convergence in most cases. However, as you remarked, it is not entirely clear if the bracketing condition is really ensured. It should be $f(b)f(α)>0$, or else some sign change in the definition has to be applied so that from the start $f(b)>0$.